# Change slide position with Firefox imacros

Tags: slider, imacros

I have been playing around with imacros for a while now, and I just can't get this to work.
I need to change the style="left: 7.69231%;" to be 0%
Thanks

This is the html code of the page:

```
<div id="slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false">
<a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 7.69231%;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your issue can be solved by means of pseudo-URL like so:

```
URL GOTO=javascript:document.querySelector("a[class='ui-slider-handle<SP>ui-state-default<SP>ui-corner-all']").style="left:<SP>0%;";undefined;
```

(Use 'iMacros for Firefox' v.8.9.7 with disabled autoupdates.)

Comment: Hi there, I think you are up to something. This actually move the slider to where I wanted, but then the macro doesn't continue.

Comment: Hi, if the macro doesn't continue working, that's quite another issue. What code do you have? What error does it give?